# Can Somebody explain what the terms in this sequence represent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence in reference is [OEIS A048144](https://oeis.org/A048144). I came across it by chance, it looks interesting, but I have no idea what anything in the comments mean. Can somebody explain what the terms in this sequence represent in non-wizard level mathematician terms?

Comment: Do you mean... what does "Number of [digraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) with [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)), with labeled [vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)) and labeled [arcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)), with $n$ arcs and with no vertex of indegree 0 or outdegree 0" mean? Follow the links I just added to this paragraph.

Comment: The 2-cent answer: digraphs are directed graphs, that is, graphs where an arc from vertex A to vertex B is considered to be different from an arc from B to A. Loops are connections from a vertex to itself. Arcs are the connections between vertices. Indegree and outdegree refer to the number of arcs arriving at a vertex or leaving the vertex, respectively.

Comment: Do they have any number theoretic significance?

Comment: The sequence or the various graph-related notions? Actually, regardless of your answer, mine is that I honestly don't know. Number theory isn't my forte. I'm not even a real mathematician. I'm a physicist.

Comment: Thats all gucci.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Its slang for its all good, its a positive remark.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Living and learning. :)

Comment: If you want to read about some interesting sequences, do a google search for Golomb Rulers. Fascinating subject.